# How to change the “/ month” on a woocommerce subscription product page to show the lengh of the subscription?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

Noob question time.

I am running Woocommerce subscriptions and have a few products with different length subscription payments; e.g

Product 01 over 3 months,
Product 02 over 5 months,
Product 03 over 12 months etc

On the product page the price is simply shown as $X / Month

How can I add the subscription length so it displays "$X over 5 months" or whatever?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: It might be helpful if not only stating some abstract requirements, but show the part of the template, which you are talking about. What have you tried so far?

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) in your question, thanks.